# create file and put content PHP

Tags: php, html

Normally I use that to add content to a page.
It works

```
 <?php
 $file = 'newpage.html';
 $current = file_get_contents($file);
 $current .= $_POST["thing"];
 file_put_contents($file, $current);
 ?>
```

Is there a way to write directly to specified div or something else,
because some parameter never change like TITLE PAGE AND SOME OTHER PARAMETERS,
and i want update only the div's.

```
 <html dir="ltr" lang="IT-IT">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
 <title>Things For Coins
 </title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="I want add content here">
 </div>

 <div id="and here">
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to do DOM parsing and editing

Comment: something like this?                                                                                $html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

Comment: DOMDocument would be better suited I think

Comment: Some PHP will be usefull, thanks